# Exception when Restoring SharePoint 2010 Site Template

Tags: sharepoint, templates

I am trying to restore a SharePoint 2010 site template (WSP) that I created.  My method of restore is to create a new site and then apply this template to it through Central Admin.  Halfway through the restore process (with the screen on "Processing..."), I get the following exception:

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: `<nativehr>`0x8107058a`</nativehr><nativestack></nativestack>`Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.

Digging into the SharePoint logs, it appears the exception is generated while activating a feature:

The element of type 'PropertyBag' for feature 'MySitePropertyBags' (id: d8c8ecfe-b8c4-42a9-87ca-a7e21eca5c58) threw an exception during activation: Invalid URI: The URI scheme is not valid.   2b46d061-e1f6-43f0-951d-d3a6252b0b77

I've tried multiple target machines, but no go.  Any help?

EDIT: It is failing because of this line in the master page:
`<link href="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/SiteAssets/css/styleSheet.css%>"  type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>`

I've tried changing ~SiteCollection to ~Site but it didn't help.  Before anyone asks, yes, that CSS file exists.  Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

F. Aquino, thank you for your help.  Your comments led me to the solution, which was to use the following line:

`<SharePoint:CssRegistration name="<% $SPUrl:~Site/SiteAssets/css/styleSheet.css %>" After="corev4.css" runat="server"/>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use $SPUrl directly in a non-server control, do it like this:

```
<link 
     href="<asp:Literal runat='server' Text='<%$SPUrl:~sitecollection/SiteAssets/css/styleSheet.css%>' />" 
     type="text/css" 
     rel="stylesheet" />
```

(Formatted to this small space)

Comment: I made that substitution and reloaded the site page that is based on the master and noticed that the CSS file is no longer applied.  So it doesn't look like that syntax works.

Comment: thats a well-known technique to get relative urls for css files, you might want to double check the url and such. You mention the css is not applied, how is it showing in the source-code?